# How to add up the value of a field in a rails find result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do:

```
@deals = Deal.find(:all)
```

I use @deals for a number of things. Every deal has a value field (how much money the deal is worth). I want to know the combined value of all deals. I have this now:

```
@deals.each { |deal| @total_value += deal.value }
```

But I'm hoping and guessing ActiveRecords have a better way to do this? Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:-

> @deals_value = Deal.sum(:value)

Thanks....

Comment: That will preform an extra query, won't it? Which is better, doing it like that or loop over a collection already in existence?

Comment: It depends on how many records are there.... if the record runs in thousands than single query is fine... More over single query will fetch only the record needed, not the whole record set... thanks...

Comment: No more than a few hundred probably.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to keep Deal.find(:all), and you want to use @deals to find the sum without a loop, try the following

```
@deals.sum(&:value)
```

Comment: You are right:p It causes an error: "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum".

Comment: Try: `@deals.inject(0) { |sum, deal| sum + (deal.value || 0) }`